# Why lapply works and apply doesn't?

Tags: r

My data:

```
 df_1 <- data.frame(
      x = replicate(
        n = 3, 
        expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)
      ), 
      y = sample(
        x = 1:3, size = 30, replace = TRUE
      )
    )
```

The follow code with `lapply` works:

```
lapply(X = names(df_1)[c(1:3)], FUN = function(x) {
  pairwise.t.test(
    x = df_1[, x], 
    g = df_1[['y']], 
    p.adj = 'bonferroni'
  )
})
```

But, with `apply` doesn't:

```
apply(X = names(df_1)[c(1:3)], MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
  pairwise.t.test(
    x = df_1[, x], 
    g = df_1[['y']], 
    p.adj = 'bonferroni'
  )
})
```

> Error in apply(X = names(df_1)[c(1:3)], MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) { : 
>     dim(X) must have a positive length

Why the problem? Are they not equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apply you should instead use

```
apply(X = df_1[1:3], MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
    pairwise.t.test(
    x = x, 
    g = df_1[['y']], 
    p.adj = 'bonferroni'
 )
})
```

that is because from `?apply`

> apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and an array of dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise.

In your attempt you are using `names(df_1)[c(1:3)]` as argument to `apply` which has

```
dim(names(df_1)[c(1:3)])[2]
#NULL
```

Hence, you get the error.

Comment: Why should one do this? Tks for answer.

Comment: @neves Added an explanation.